# Facing issue with length of CHAP-Password value - Radius Authentication

Tags: freeradius, radius, chap

I have constructed the access request packet with username and CHAP password attributes.
Not able to authenticate with the radius sever
Checked wire shark.
Found out that in the AVP -
AVP: t=CHAP-Password(3) l=18 val=[wrong length for CHAP-Password]
Type: 3
Length: 18
What could be the possible reason for this?

Thank you

I tried debugging the length being set
Could not get any leads from that.